# Make button disabled with if and setAttribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I wish my decrease-button to become disabled if the number of element is 1. Button should not be able to be -1. But should make number 2 become 1 for example.

```js
let element = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(element)
element.setAttribute('id', 'bet-size')
let text = document.createTextNode('1')
element.appendChild(text)

let click = document.createElement('input')
click.setAttribute('type', 'button')
click.setAttribute('id', 'decrease')
document.body.appendChild(click)

click.addEventListener('click', () => {
  element.textContent = Number(element.textContent) - 1
  if (element.textContent === 1) {
    click.setAttribute('disabled', true)
  } else if (element.textContent > 1)
    click.setAttribute('disabled', false)
})
```

Where I need help is how to properly write the if statement using setAttribute (and maybe removeAttribute on my other button that increases the number?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare with the `"0"`, not `1` when disabling. It has to be a string since you use `===` for the comparison.

To enable the button you have to use `removeAttribute`.

```js
let element = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(element)
element.setAttribute('id', 'bet-size')
let text = document.createTextNode('1')
element.appendChild(text)

let click = document.createElement('input')
click.setAttribute('type', 'button')
click.setAttribute('id', 'decrease')
click.value = "-";
document.body.appendChild(click)

click.addEventListener('click', () => {
  element.textContent = Number(element.textContent) - 1
  if (element.textContent === "0") {
    click.setAttribute('disabled', true)
  } else if (element.textContent > 1)
    click.removeAttribute('disabled')
})

let increase = document.createElement('input')
increase.setAttribute('type', 'button')
increase.id = 'increase';
increase.value = '+';
document.body.appendChild(increase);

increase.addEventListener('click', () => {
  element.textContent = Number(element.textContent) + 1
  if (element.textContent === "0") {
    click.setAttribute('disabled', true)
  } else if (element.textContent > 1)
    click.removeAttribute('disabled')
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. To add possibility to change with keyboard may I implement new event or add on excisting?

Comment: You can use a `keyup` event on the `document` object. You might want to put the common code into a separate function so you can call it from all the event listeners.